# Custom Rewriting to Plugin with Parameters

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting

I'm really stuck on the WP_Rewrite functionality...

### What I have

I have a plugin that's rendered using a shortcode and is displaying full-site content. E.g.:

```
//?p=2 (maps to domain.tld/myplugin/)
[my-plugin]
```

This plugin basically is a directory of some list-content.

### What I want

Basically I want to achieve nice urls for the categorisation of the list content displayed by the plugin. E.g.:

```
domain.tld/myplugin/?filter=someFilter // works but is ugly

domain.tld/myplugin/someFilter         // is what I want
```

### What I tried

So I've tried the approach using `add_rewrite_rule` as well as modifying:

```
global $wp_rewrite

$customRules = [
    "myplugin/([^/]+)/?" => "?p=2&filter=$matches[1]" // try 1.1
    "myplugin/([^/]+)/?" => "/myplugin/filter=$matches[1]" // try 2.1
];

$wp_rewrite->rules = $customRules + $wp_rewrite->rules; // try 1
$wp_rewrite->extra_rules_top = $customRules + $wp_rewrite->extra_rules_top // try 2
```

However none of my rewrites work. The best I can achieve is to simply get redirected to `/myplugin/` without any parameter added to the page. This, I assume, is due to Wordpress matching `?p=2` to `/myplugin/` as defined within the permalink structure of the page. So my guess is that parameters simply are stripped from the rule.

## So my question:

How can I achieve what I want? Do I really have to write the rewrite-rules hard into the .htaccess?

### The 50% solution

So after reading [this awesome article](http://blog.pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api/) I was able to get at least something working. Ultimately I'm able to achieve

```
domain.tld/myplugin/filter/someFilter
a syntax like "param/value"
```

This is done by `add_rewrite_endpoint()` and adding the filter to the `query_vars`. For now this thing is what I do but ultimately I'd really like to get it down to:

```
domain.tld/myplugin/someFilter
```

So help will still be much appreciated ;)

## Update 1st solution by @websupporter

Tried the approach given by a user here and it still doesn't work. I deactivated all plugins and it still doesn't work.

The only thing that could interfere at this point as far as I know is the `.htaccess` but to me this one looks pretty standard as well..

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Post the code you're using at the moment.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic thought this would be enough ;) However check current answer by websupporter This one doesn't work on my installation either and this is with all other plugins deactivated aside from the one-file-plugin he wrote and appears to be working on his end.

Comment: The `.htaccess` won't be interfering, I assure you. This just maps all non-file/directory requests to `index.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach should work for you:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Rewrite Shortcode
 **/

 add_shortcode( 'myplugin', 'mp_shortcode' );
 function mp_shortcode(){
    return '<p>Filter: ' . get_query_var( 'filter' ) . '</p>';
 }

 add_action( 'init', 'mp_rewrite' );
 function mp_rewrite(){
    $post_id = 2;
    add_rewrite_rule( 'myplugin/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?p=' . $post_id . '&filter=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%filter%', '([^/]+)' );
 }
?>
```

I developed it quickly as a small plugin, so I was able to test it myself. While you work with the global `$wp_rewrite` I thought it might be better to use the functions, which are documented in the Codex. Basically just, because I know them better :) So I can't exaktly tell, what you did wrong, but I can tell, what I do differently.

You're approach:

```
"myplugin/([^/]+)/?" => "?p=2&filter=$matches[1]
```

I've explicitly told WordPress to use the *index.php* as it is also done in the documents. And I use `add_rewrite_tag()` to generate a new query variable, which I can read with `get_query_var()` in my shortcode.

**Attention: Flush the Rules!**
When you use these functions, you have to go to Settings > Permalinks and click the "update"-button. If you don't do this, the new rules won't be active. You could also use `flush_rewrite_rules()` during the activation of the plugin. An example on how to do this is given in the Codex.

Docs:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

Comment: OK, so I was able to test this now and sadly I get literally the same result as on my tries. Here's what I did:
I copied your content to `myplugin.php` inside `/plugins` and activated the plugin on the backend.
After activation i went to `Setting > Permalinks` and pressed `Save Changes` to flush the rewrite rules.
I then created a new page using the shortcode `[myplugin]`.
I went to my installation `foo.dom/myplugin/123` => it redirected me to `foo.dom/myplugin/` and the output was `filter:` - no more. :'( There's no other rewrite stuff ongoing, I disabled my plugin. My htaccess is default,too

Comment: thats quite strange to be honest. can you try it locally on a complete clean installation? i know, you say, nothing is going on, but it works for me. this is why i am puzzled. "I then created a new page using the shortcode [myplugin]" you mean, you have created a new page and in there, you used the shortcode, right?

Comment: Sad news... here's what I did:

Download WP (4.1.1), extract, copy myplugin.php // cd wp-dir // php -S localhost:9090

Create new Page with the given shortcode as body content. Synchronize page id within myplugin.php

Enable Plugin on backend // go to Settings > Permalinks and save them a few times ("Post Name" setting)

foo.dom/myplugin/123 redirects to foo.dom/myplugin with no filter being displayed.

Comment: the rewrite_rule() is set to 'top', right? check your rules with https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/ if they are placed correctly. *running out of ideas* :/

Comment: Got it working. `?p=` vs. `?page_id=`. I got really confused why it kept redirecting to the page without any parameters. I noticed that internally `page_id` is used. So my assumption is: `?p=` does an redirect to `?page_id=` and strips all other stuff. I have no proof for this code-based, but ultimately with using `page_id` it works. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: ouch! i should have thought of this, when you wrote 'page' instead of 'post'. Glad it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `add_rewrite_rule()` function, please note that the code is untested but it should work depending on your specific use. If you also need to set a **post_id**, just add it to the `index.php?p=X...` string.

```
function myplugin_filter_add_rewrite_rules()
{
  // Allow for /myplugin/filter/someFilter
  add_rewrite_rule('myplugin/filter/([^/]+)/?$',
   'index.php?filter=$matches[1]',
   'top');

  // Optionally keep pagination /myplugin/filter/someFilter/page/2
  add_rewrite_rule('myplugin/filter/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)?$',
   'index.php?filter=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
   'top');
}

add_filter('init', 'myplugin_filter_add_rewrite_rules');
```

As already stated, don't forget to flush the rules by visiting **Settings > Permalinks** or use `flush_rewrite_rules()` in the plugin activation (don't execute it at every page load).

Comment: Hey gyo, please see what I wrote under websupporters answer. I begin to think that the problem may be completely elsewhere as his solution doesn't work in my place with all other plugins deactivated aside from his. Added my .htaccess into the question as well, I'm really getting more n more clueless about this.